# How to get background of textview in pygobject “gtk3”?

Tags: python, gtk3

I'd like to get the current background color of my textview to change it and restore it later.

here what I tried:

```
context = textview.get_style_context()
state = Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL
color = context.get_background_color(state)
```

I tried all possible states, but none returns the correct background color (white in my case)

Any idea how to get it?

Comment: it happens the same to me :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you specific problem is without seeing more code, but here is a quick example that overrides the background and then restores it on a button click:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import sys


class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Textview example", application=app)
        self.set_default_size(250, 100)
        self.set_border_width(10)

        self.view = Gtk.TextView()
        self.style_context = self.view.get_style_context()
        self.default_bg_color = self.style_context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
        self.view.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,
                                            Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))

        self.btn = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.btn.connect("clicked", self.on_btn_clicked)

        box = Gtk.VBox()
        box.pack_start(self.view, True, True, 0)
        box.pack_start(self.btn, False, False, 0)
        self.add(box)

    def on_btn_clicked(self, widget):
        current_bg = self.style_context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
        if current_bg == self.default_bg_color:
            self.view.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,
                                                Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))
        else:
            self.view.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, 
                                                self.default_bg_color)


class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Comment: Hi,
this script does not work for me. the default_bg_color is (0, 0, 0, 0) for me, as explained in my question. So I get the black background, but when clicking the button I don't get the white background back, but the grey color of the rest of the window.